# Marshmallow doesn't show the "change default dialer app" popout

Tags: android

I want to change my default dialer app and searched for some articles.

But when I'm in the test, I encounter problem my real phone(Android 6.0) doesn't show the pop window. 

[InRealPhoneTest.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gU9zz.png)

So I'm attempting to test in a virtual machine(android 6.0), it works perfectly.

[InVirtualMachineTest.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOldf.png)

below are my codes:

Application.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.slb.test1">
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:directBootAware="true"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:process=":interim"
        android:resizeableActivity="true"
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="tel"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

MainApplication.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_SET_DEFAULT_DIALER = 289;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
public void ViewClick(View view){
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(TelecomManager.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER);
        intent=intent.putExtra(TelecomManager.EXTRA_CHANGE_DEFAULT_DIALER_PACKAGE_NAME, getPackageName());
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_SET_DEFAULT_DIALER);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if(requestCode==REQUEST_CODE_SET_DEFAULT_DIALER){
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            Toast.makeText(this,"accept",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else if(resultCode==RESULT_CANCELED){
            Toast.makeText(this,"cancel",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"unknown",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}}
```

My purpose wants to change the default app dialer through InCallService service class, I'm just testing the pop window.
when I process program in a virtual machine of android 6.0, I can choose whether to accept or cancel in a popout. however, when I process program in a real phone that version is android 6.0, the phone doesn't appear the popout.

So, I can't understand why it doesn't work on the real phone. can you tell me something about it?. your answer will be appreciated.